# how to view a foto from mysql to html with GO language?

Tags: html, mysql, database, image, go

here is my code
this is a code to insert into the database

```
func Create(category entities.Category) bool {
    result, err := config.DB.Exec(`
        INSERT INTO categories (name, create_at, path)
        VALUE (?, ?, ?)`,
        category.Name, category.CreatedAt, category.Path,
    )

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    LastInsertId, err := result.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return LastInsertId > 0
}
```

and this code shows data in HTML

```
func GetAll() []entities.Category {
    rows, err := config.DB.Query(`SELECT * FROM categories`)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var categories []entities.Category

    for rows.Next() {
        var category entities.Category
        err := rows.Scan(&category.Id, &category.Name, &category.CreatedAt, &category.Path)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        categories = append(categories, category)
    }

    return categories
}
func Detail(id int) entities.Category {
    row := config.DB.QueryRow(`SELECT id, name, path FROM categories WHERE id = ?`, id)

    var category entities.Category
    if err := row.Scan(&category.Id, &category.Name, &category.Path); err != nil{
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return category
}
```

How to show an image?

I need this night :)

Thank you